# Kotlin synthetic extension for view

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I have a layout with some views, one of them has the id `title_whalemare`

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.controller_settings.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view_double_text.*

class MainSettingsController : BaseMvpController<MvpView, MvpPresenter>() {

    val title: TextView = title_whalemare

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.controller_settings
    }
}
```

I try find it with `kotlin extensions`, but I can't because I get the following error

*None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch*
[image: None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch]

`controller_settings.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title_whalemare"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit: synthetics are now deprecated and will be removed. Please see [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/discontinuing-kotlin-synthetics-for-views.html) for details.**

---

What the error is trying to tell you is that you can only access views with Extensions from either within an `Activity` or a `Fragment`. This is because it does the exact same thing to find the views with the given IDs as what you'd be doing manually, it just calls `Activity.findViewById()` and `Fragment.getView().findViewById()`, and then does the type cast to the specific subclass of `View`. I'm guessing that your Controller is not an `Activity` or `Fragment`.

There's another way to use Extensions, if you can pass in the root view of your layout to your controller somehow. Then you could do the following:

```
val title: TextView = rootView.title_whalemare
```

Again, this is just replacing the `View.findViewById()` call and the type cast.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter to write: `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.*`.

Comment: if your class is fragment or activity class then you should invalidate cache and restart, the error will be gone. If you are doing it outside fragment/activity then you need to do exactly as the answer says.

Comment: Is there a much cleaner way to access these views without calling rootView outside Activity or Fragment?